# i am referencing coursename in student table from course table but getting error "not the same data type as referencing column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I create a course table where cId as INT is primary key and course as VARCHAR
and second table student where course is varchar and am taking reference from course table in cId column

```
CREATE TABLE Course (
    cID int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, 
    course varchar(10)
)


CREATE TABLE Student(
    ID int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1001,1) PRIMARY KEY ,
    StudentName varchar(10), 
    RollNo int,
    course  varchar(10) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Course(cID), 
);
```

Comment: `course` must be an `int` to reference the `cID` from `Course`

Comment: And if, as most student do, a student can register on more than one course, you will need a cross reference table to link one student to many courses.

Comment: i've done this but after when i try to do inner join it returns error says cant convert int to string

Comment: I think what you really need to do is start by searching for **and reading** a "Relational Database Design for beginners" tutorial

Comment: That DDL will not run on MYSQL! That is SQLServer syntax and not MySQL. Are you using SQLServer of MySQL?

Comment: its microsoft sql server management studio 2018

Comment: hy its working now joins are working i was confused about the data type not its cleared its solved

Answer (score 0):

```
create table #course(cid int identity(1,1)primary key,
course varchar(20))

insert into #course values('science'),('eng'),('maths'),('biology')
cid  course
1   science
2   eng
3   maths
4   biology

create table #student(id int identity(1001,1)primary key,
studentName varchar(30), RollNO int,
courseid int foreign key references #course(cid))
```

Refer the course name my courseid , data will be in normalize form

```
insert into #student values('john',101,1),('ker',102,3),('ghm',103,2),  ('ahm',104,3)
id     studentname   rollno courseid
1001    john            101     1
1002    ker             102     3
1003    ghm             103     2
1004    ahm             104     3
```